# how can I upload a image on server side in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a web project that save  photo to image folder(i used FileUpload) it work in client side but when i upload my website on my host it didnt work anymore ,
this is my code

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Image/") + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
```

Comment: Is there any error; please share us the exception message if any

Comment: It seems fine..can you show us the exception..??

Comment: Are you using shared hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably write permission issues for your `Image folder`,Got to your server C-Panel and give necessary permissions to the folder required.

For more on permissions see this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Comment: thanks  ,but I have windows host could u tell me how can I give  permissions to the folder?

Comment: do you have access(username/password) to your server,then in the control panel there will be a link for 'File manager' or 'File sysytem' etc,navigate to the Image folder and click something like 'edit settings' and give 'full access' to the folder.

Comment: I went to file manager and change the folder permission to both read and write but i have still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exception, the most likely problems are

1. Permissions -- as others have stated. You need to look up the username of your application pool and grant that user appropriate permissions to your `image` subfolder
2. Does the `image` subfolder even exist?
3. File size exceeds server limits. For more information on this see this post:

[Recommendations on Max File Upload Size in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127216/recommendations-on-max-file-upload-size-in-iis)

Answer (score 0):

Please Check you should give Write Permission on the Image folder.

Answer (score -1):

check below code :

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"Image/") + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
```

i think this will work. Please let me know.

Comment: No it won't. All you did was add an `@`, which tells C# to ignore single `\\` characters in the string. Depending on the structure of his app, it may actually upload to the wrong place....

Comment: you can also try above code without " @ ". only i have removed " ~/ " from Server.MapPath(). If you are using Server.MapPath it means you are actually considering virtual path of your app directory. And if you use " ~/ " which is same as Server.MapPath().